# Delegate scroller to children when being compliant to max-height

Tags: css

I have a list which will contain many entries in a `position: fixed` div. And so, I want the `max-height` to be the screen's height, but I do not want the main div to have the scroller, I want the child list to have the scroller.

I have seen that you can make the parent div `display: flex` with the `max-height: 100%` and the child `flex-1` with `overflow: auto`, and that works fine as long as it's a direct child. However, in my case the list is nested inside two divs.

How would I be able to solve this?

Is there any way to set max-height to parent's remaining space, for example?

Example using Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container-fluid position-fixed top-0 h-100 mh-100">
    <div class="row">
        Some other columns and information...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-8">
            <ul class="overflow-auto">
                <li>Entry 1</li>
                ...
                <li>Entry 1000</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue when asking this kind of question. (Instead of just a vague verbal explanation, which on top still would require everyone reading the question to create their own example.)

Comment: I don't really understand... can you please provide a simple example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I posted a simple example